# The following packages have unmet dependencies: libfcgi-bin

Tags: package-management, upgrade, qgis

I tried to install "qgis" and "qgis server", but I failed to do so and I think certain packages got conflicted with ones I already have on my system.

Now I can't upgrade through "sudo apt-get upgrade" and also can't install new packages; when I do so I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfcgi-bin : Depends: libfcgi0ldbl but it is not installed
 qgis-server : Depends: libfcgi0ldbl but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also can't purge either qgis-server or libfcgi-bin, if I do so I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfcgi-bin : Depends: libfcgi0ldbl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I want to get rid of qgis-server and anything related to this problem so I can resume the system normally

Comment: Did you remember to enable the 'Universe' pocket of the Ubuntu repository? `libfcgi0ldbl` is in Universe.

Comment: @user535733 what do you mean by the universe "pocket"? libfcgi0ldbl doesn't exist in the software center, neither does it exist in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: `libfcgi0ldbl` is available for all supported Ubuntu versions https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libfcgi0ldbl&searchon=names ...  A line with **universe** must be present in /etc/apt/sources.list !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: I managed to solve it by using the following command "sudo dpkg -P libfcgi0ldbl", then again for qgis-server sudo dpkg -P qgis-server .

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by using the following command "sudo dpkg -P libfcgi0ldbl", then again for qgis-server sudo dpkg -P qgis-server .